# How to apply json content for html attribute

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to add json object for html arrtibute content but not working.I have tried many ways but I do not know how to set that.if any one know about that please help to resolve this issue.

javascript:

```
   var validatorValue='{ 
            "picker":{
                    "allow":
                        {
                        "message": "Content loram ipsom"
                        },
                    "past":
                        {
                        "message": "lorem issom"
                        }  
                }
           }' ;

   var daterestrictValue="{'range': {'start': '2019-10-30','end': '2019-12-30'}}";


   var myinputValue="{'date':'tomorrow'}";

$("#mydiv").html("<div input="true" validator='+validatorValue+' date-restrict='+daterestrictValue+'  my-input='+myinputValue+'></div>");
```

Comment: your use of quotation marks is incorrect. Change the last line to ```$("#mydiv").html(`div input = "true" validator = '${validatorValue}' date-restrict = '${daterestrictValue}' my-input = '${myinputValue}'></div>`);```

Comment: try wrapping your string with Template-strings(https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings)

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with your code (aside from line-breaks in string literals) it the mis-matched quotes in the HTML string you build. However, even after correcting those you will have issues placing serialised JSON within attributes as it too contains double quotes which will break the HTML syntax.

Also note that you're creating non-standard attributes in the HTML you create which may cause unexpected issues in your UI and JS.

An alternative way to approach this is to work with the values as objects (instead of strings). You can use jQuery to set the `data` of the element using those objects, like this:

```js
var validatorValue = { "picker": { "allow": { "message": "Content loram ipsom" }, "past": { "message": "lorem issom" } } }
var daterestrictValue = { 'range': { 'start': '2019-10-30', 'end': '2019-12-30' } }
var myinputValue = { 'date': 'tomorrow' };

var $newDiv = $('<div data-input="true">Click me</div>').appendTo('#mydiv');
$newDiv.data({
  "validator": validatorValue,
  "date-restrict": daterestrictValue,
  "my-input": myinputValue
});

// for testing
$('#mydiv div').on('click', function() {
  console.log($(this).data('validator'));
  console.log($(this).data('date-restrict'));
  console.log($(this).data('my-input'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

Comment: 'Not working' isn't a helpful diagnosis. You can see this works fine in the example above, therefore there must be some other underlying difference in your version causing a problem.

Comment: Any other method is there?

Comment: Actully my code look like $('<datepicker data-input="true">Click me</datepicker >').appendTo('#mydiv');    datepicker  is global component..If I use your idea that josn data is not taking

Comment: There is no `<datepicker />` element. Are you using a non-standard doctype? Or did you mean `<input type="date" />`

Comment: I have created already <datepicker> component. this is global component...just I am setting json data for that

Comment: If I use your concept datepicker is coming but json data not applying

Comment: How have you created the `<datepicker />` element? It's entirely non standard so the implementation of `data` may be flaky

Comment: Sorry..like this <datepicker-custom>

Answer (score 0):

this code save object in html element.

good luck

```
var validatorValue="{ 'picker':{'allow':{'message': 'Content loram ipsom'},'past':{'message': 'lorem issom'}}}";
var daterestrictValue="{'range': {'start': '2019-10-30','end': '2019-12-30'}}";
var myinputValue="{'date':'tomorrow'}";
    $("#mydiv").html(`
    <div input='true' validator="${validatorValue}" date-restrict="${daterestrictValue}" my-input="${myinputValue}">ggg</div>`);
```

Comment: Tried but not working..getting Error: unexpected token $ in JSON

Comment: You have any solution?

Comment: this is new feature in es6

Comment: I am using jquery 1.7.1